# Changed DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST path, but RMAN still backs up to the old path?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, archive-log

I just recently changed the DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST parameter to point to a new directory path. However, I noticed only some archivelogs and backup sets are going to this new directory path and some are still going to the old path. Why is that?

Furthermore, some of the old archivelogs aren't getting deleted when they're past the retention policy. Do these need to get manually removed? If so, is there an RMAN command to manually remove them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that your backup scripts are written in such a way as to not be utilizing the FRA.  We'd have to actually _see the code_ in order to assess what's going on. Please update your question and post the _formatted_ backup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your backup scrpit?

After changing DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST to new location -  Copy all archive log file which is generated in old and copy to new location. using OS level copy command.

Then catalog the new DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST

```
RMAN> catalog db_recovery_file_dest;  ( else) 
RMAN> catalog start with 'New location Path'; 
RMAN> crosscheck archivelog all;
RMAN> delete expired archivelog all;
```

Comment: When you say OS level command, you mean using "cp" in Linux for example? Some of these arc files have remained long after the retention policy even though RMAN still detects them. Should I just remove them with the "rm" command? I'm also having trouble figuring how to get the backup scripts.

Comment: Yes I am referring to cp command - Lets move all the archive logs from old location to new location - Then do above steps i.e., catalog/crosscheck/delete - So rman will take care to delete all the archive logs which are expired.

Comment: I will perform this tomorrow in my work hours and let you know the results.

Comment: I've run out of space in the filesystem and there are still many more flash recovery areas to move over. Is it possible to simply run the rm command and remove the backups that are obviously expired?

Comment: When I ran the mv command to move the files into the new FRA path, it modified the creation date to the time I moved them. So the catalog read them as new backups.

Comment: No rman  will not consider mv date creation time.

Comment: I ran the crosscheck, and nothing was expired or obsolete. It lists the moved backups as newer backups.